# WinHttpAddRequestHeaders: 87 when sending certificate in header - c++

Tags: c++, http, authentication, http-headers, cpprest-sdk

I'm running into an issue when trying to send certificate in the header. This is my code

```
    PCCERT_CONTEXT pccertContext = GetCertificate();

    DWORD size = 0;
    CryptBinaryToString(pccertContext->pbCertEncoded, pccertContext->cbCertEncoded, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, NULL, &size);

    LPTSTR dest = static_cast<LPTSTR> (HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, size * sizeof(TCHAR)));

    CryptBinaryToString(pccertContext->pbCertEncoded, pccertContext->cbCertEncoded, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, dest, &size);
    HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_NO_SERIALIZE, dest);

    http_request request(methods::GET);
    request.headers().add(L"client-certificate", dest);
    request.set_request_uri(getUri());
    client::http_client client(web::uri(StringUtils::ToWString(*url)), config);
    const auto response = client.request(request).get();
```

It fails when I try to make the request. Appreciate any help regarding where I'm going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. dest was a multi-line string. That's why http_request was rejecting the header. Did the following to fix it:

```
    wstring ws(dest);
    ws.erase(remove(ws.begin(), ws.end(), '\r'), ws.end());
    ws.erase(remove(ws.begin(), ws.end(), '\n'), ws.end());

    // Send ws in the header instead
    http_request request(methods::GET);
    request.headers().add(L"client-certificate", ws);
    request.set_request_uri(getUri());
    client::http_client client(web::uri(StringUtils::ToWString(*url)), config);
    const auto response = client.request(request).get();
```